# change class of <td> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the class of the td element within the loop however i don't really have a solution that works, would somebody be able to help me please, thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>VAR (%)</td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc1"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc2"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc3"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc4"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc5"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc6"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc7"></i></td>
</tr>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 $.post(url, filteredObject, function (data) {
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        $('#varperc' + (i + 1).toString()).text(numberWithCommas(data[i].varperc));

        var cls = parseInt($('#varperc' + (i + 1).toString()).text());

        if (cls < 0) {
            $('#varperc' + (i + 1).toString()).addClass("fa fa-level-down");
            $('#varperc' + (i + 1).toString()).removeClass("fa-level-up");
            $('.text-primary').removeClass('primary');
            $('.text-').addClass('warning');
        }
        else {
            $('#varperc' + (i + 1).toString()).addClass("fa fa-level-up");
            $('#varperc' + (i + 1).toString()).removeClass("fa-level-down");
            $('.text-primary').removeClass('primary');
            $('.text-').addClass('navy');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: well the text-primary class is not changing...

Comment: maybe change $('.text-primary').removeClass('primary'); to $('.text-primary').removeClass('text-primary');

Comment: use $.each to iterate check my answer for detail

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$('.text-primary').removeClass('primary')
```

I assume you want

```
$('.text-primary').removeClass('text-primary')
```

You can add a different class instead using

```
$('.text-primary').removeClass('text-primary').addClass('navy')
```

Then, the

```
$('.text-').addClass('navy');
```

is obsolete (I don't think it was working anyway before).

See [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) docs.

Comment: but then the class would be nothing..how would i assign a new class to it?

Comment: I extended the answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on you comment that you would like to change the .text-primary class I assuming you would like it to be changed to 'text-navy' or 'text-warning'. In this case change:

```
 $('.text-primary').removeClass('primary');
 $('.text-').addClass('navy');
```

to:

```
$('.text-primary').removeClass('text-primary');
$('.text-').addClass('text-navy');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is no class `primary`, css classes don't works this way, you just have the `.text-primary` to become `.text-navy` so then you should remove `.text-primary` and add `.text-navy` class. Or you may change your system to work with these classes instead.

You may consider using this code above:

```
 var $varperc = $('#varperc' + (i + 1).toString());

 $varperc
    .closest('.text-primary')
    .removeClass('text-primary')
    .addClass('text-navy');
```

Answer (score 0):

i think better and dynamic approach to achieve this is to use $.each loop of jquery

try it like

your html

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc1"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc2"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc3"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc4"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc5"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc6"></i></td>
    <td class="text-primary"> <i class="" id="varperc7"></i></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

and js

```
$.each($('table tr td'),function(i,j){
    $(this).find('i[id*=varperc]').text(numberWithCommas(data[i].varperc));

        var cls = parseInt($(this).find('i[id*=varperc]').text('test'+i));

        if (cls < 0) {
            $(this).find('i[id*=varperc]').addClass("fa fa-level-down");
            $(this).find('i[id*=varperc]').removeClass("fa-level-up");
            $(this).removeClass('text-primary');
            $(this).addClass('warning');
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('i[id*=varperc]').addClass("fa fa-level-up");
            $(this).find('i[id*=varperc]').removeClass("fa-level-down");
            $(this).removeClass('text-primary');
            $(this).addClass('navy');
        }
});
```